# Why do french say "animal de compagnie" instead of "animal"

Tags: vocabulaire

Why do they stretch it unnecessarily? In duolingo, "animal de compagnie" is correct, "animal" is wrong. Why is that?

For example: *j'ai un animal de compagnie.*

Comment: It sounds like this is about a specific Duolingo exercise.  What is the sentence Duolingo is asking you to translate?  And it’s worth noting that Duolingo isn’t infallible. Sometimes its suggested translations aren’t quite idiomatic in the source or target language; sometimes its suggested translation is good, but it rejects some reasonable alternative translations.

Comment: yes i know duolingo sometimes spelling some weird words but i've seen this many times and i wanted to ask why. Sentence was "I have an animal" (maybe pet i'm not sure)

Comment: The sentences *"mon mari est un animal"* and *"mon mari est un animal de compagnie"* have very, very different meanings. They are actually straight opposites. (this is a joke)

Answer (score 14):

If the goal is to translate "I have a pet", then *j'ai un animal de compagnie* is a correct translation while *j'ai un animal* alone doesn't necessarily mean it is a pet.

[pet](https://www.duolingo.com/dictionary/French/animal%20de%20compagnie/532c899a37b49ef4ac13160c0c0a356c)

[image]

[animal](https://www.duolingo.com/dictionary/French/animal/e71591506ec66d8fc178509dbe25c715)

[image]

Comment: i thought it meant i have an animal.. thats why i'm asked. good to know thanks.

Comment: It does mean "I have an animal". Not all animals are pets. For example a cow or a boar aren't. Animals contrast to plants.

Answer (score 9):

An *animal de compagnie* (pet) is the animal who **keeps company** with his owner hence **compagnie** also called *animal domestique*, where *domestique* is the adjective of *domicile* meaning a **house** whether it means a flat or a farm or any kind of living arrangement. Whereas *an animal* is just that, it could be wild, dangerous, not necessarily living in your home and keeping you company.

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe farm animals (pigs, cows...) are 'animaux domestiques' although they are not 'animaux de compagnie'.

Comment: @vc74 The Larousse also says this: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/domestique/26365 (the "en vue d'obtenir une production" part").

Comment: Would also depend on which French-speaking region/country...in QC we don't use domestique for farm animals and rather 'de compagnie' and 'domestiques' are interchangeable as house/companion animal.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in English, and in the US in particular, a pet is sometimes called a "companion animal," which would seem to be a direct, literal translation of "animal de compagnie."