# Different ways to say « pets »

Tags: vocabulaire

I am confused on the difference between animaux de compagnie et animaux domestiques. If someone could explain the difference I would be most grateful.

Comment: Have you looked at a dictionnary first?

Comment: See also https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43381/1109

Comment: Think of the difference between _pets_ and _domesticated animals_ in English.

Answer (score 11):

There is a subtle difference between the two terms:

- "*Animaux de compagnie*" generally refers to "Pets", animals kept for companionship and pleasure and they are usually considered members of the family such as dogs and cats.
- "*Animaux domestiques*" is a broader term that encompasses all animal living with humans in a domestic setting, whether for companionship, work or other purposes. This can include not only pets such as cats and dogs but also domesticated farm animals like cows, horses, sheep, etc.

Comment: Would a stray dog be called an _animal de compagnie_? I think it wouldn't, right? Just like it wouldn't be called a _pet_ in English. Isn't that distinction also part of the answer? That an animal needs to actually be someone's pet in order for it to be called an  _animal de compagnie_?

Comment: yes, in both French and English, we typically refer to an animal as a "pet" or "animal de compagnie" when it's someone's companion and under their care. Stray dogs, which are homeless and without owners, wouldn't fall into this category.